# Moment js get number of week of year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Someone can describe me why the following returns `1`?

```
moment("2017-12-31").weeks()
```

But the following returns `52`?

```
moment("2017-12-30").weeks()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

> Because different locales define week of year numbering differently,
>   Moment.js added moment#week to get/set the localized week of the year.

Since the 31.12 is a Sunday, it looks like the weeks in your country starts at Sunday.

Answer (score 4):

From moment.js documentation:

> The week of the year varies depending on which day is the first day of the week (Sunday, Monday, etc), and which week is the first week of the year.
>
> For example, in the United States, Sunday is the first day of the week. The week with January 1st in it is the first week of the year.
>
> In France, Monday is the first day of the week, and the week with January 4th is the first week of the year.

Answer (score 4):

So, if you are having problems getting the right week number use .isoWeek()

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var weeknumber = moment("11-26-2016", "MMDDYYYY").week();
    alert(weeknumber);
  });

   $(document).ready(function(){
    var weeknumber = moment("11-26-2016", "MMDDYYYY").isoWeek();
    alert(weeknumber);
  });
```

That will work for you

Answer (score 2):

Because the 31st falls on the first week of the next year, hence the `1`; the `31`st is a Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

```
moment().weeksInYear();
```

Gets the number of weeks according to locale in the current moment's year.

```
moment().isoWeeksInYear();
```

Gets the number of weeks in the current moment's year, according to [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).